# List of the $(xxx) macro in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, macros

I would like to establish a list of all the visual studio macro that can be used in the post-build event script.

- $(Configuration) : Name of the current build configuration (ie: Debug or Release).

Comment: See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/42x5kfw4.aspx).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Just click the Macros >> button in the post build events dialog. I includes the list and a preview of what the result will be. Here is a list any way:

```
$(OutDir)
$(ConfigurationName)
$(ProjectName)
$(TargetName)
$(TargetPath)
$(ProjectFileName)
$(TargetExt)
$(TargetFileName)
$(DevEnvDir)
$(TargetDir)
$(ProjectDir)
$(SolutionFileName)
$(SolutionPath)
$(SolutionDir)
```

Comment: I don't think Visual Studio's list is all inclusive. $(MSBuildToolsPath) and $(registry:[key]@[value]) also works for me in VS2010.

Answer (score 4):

The official Microsoft documentation for VS2017 is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2017) and for VS 2019 is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 2):

While it won't include project-specific macros, if you open the Developer Command Prompt for VS (It's in your Start Menu, it's like cmd.exe but with VsDevCmd.bat as part of the launch options), you can type `set` and it will list out all that it can see, including things like FramewokDir, WindowsSdkDir, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Often changing probably, now:
[VS 2015](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-140), [VS 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-150) & [VS 2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=msvc-160)